# Issue with XQUERY in LINUX Environment

Tags: java, xquery

I am using XQUERY in my JAVA project for XML files data read/modify/delete.
for using XQUERY from JAVA I'm using saxon9he.jar file.

Here the problem is the XQUERY queries are working fine in WINDOWS but not working in "RED HAT LINUX". I got this problem while modifying a particular tag data in XML file.

Can any one tell me what to do to fix this issue. It's an urgent.

Comment: What makes you think the issue is "RED HAT LINUX"?  Perhaps you have made a mistake in your implementation?

Comment: Did you check the Java versions you use on both Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 2):

To run saxon from the commandline, here are instructions from docs

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.xml

This sounds like a Java issue e.g. you sure you have java on the machine ?

I would first try to run saxon without any input to confirm it runs properly to diagnose if your environment is setup properly.